How to schedule a task in cloud function trigger and then stop it?
Basically, I am working on a system in which some users (dispatchers) can create calls, and then other users (volunteers) can respond to those calls.
Every call can have a status of open (default), covered (done by volunteer), closed (also done by volunteer).
Now what I need to do is whenever a call is created (it's status is open), I want to schedule a function to send a notification every 2 minutes, until it's status is changed to covered.
I tried to use setInterval() in firebase cloud function, but I read somewhere that it's not possible to keep a cloud function alive for more than 9 minutes, and also I was facing some issue to cancel the timer once the call is covered.
Now I found cloud task to be something useful for me, but I can't understand how would I start it, once the call is created, and then cancel it once the call is covered.
I have worked in firebase databases a lot of times, but cloud functions are something new to me, so I am quite a beginner to this :(

"I can't understand" is really hard to help with. Did you read the documentation on scheduling Cloud Tasks in Cloud Functions for Firebase yet? Did you try to implement what is shown there? Was there an error message?

There is no magic service to provide notification for a while and then stop. To achieve this pattern you have to build it by yourselves.
You can imagine 2 implementation:

Scheduler
Task


For the scheduler option, you can create a scheduler when a call is created. Set the frequency to 2 minutes (*/2 * * * *).
The invoked endpoint checks the call status:

if it's covered, delete the scheduler configuration
if not, do the notification

The problem is: I don't know if there is quotas on scheduler. If you use Cloud Scheduler, I know there is at least an associated cost. Personally, it's not my preferred option

If you use the task option, my preferred option, you can you can create a first task 2 minutes in the future when a call is created.
The invoked endpoint checks the call status:

if it's covered, do nothing
if not, do the notification, and create a new task in 2 minutes in the future.

